# Mutate Command Making Multiple Columns Instead of Just One Column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use mutate to create a new column, but instead of one I get 7.

```
Output<-Total.Cancer%>%
  gather(Cancer,Total)%>%
  bind_cols(D.Total)%>%
  bind_cols(Death.Total)%>%
  mutate(Non.D.Total=Total-D.Total)
```

And I get an output that creates multiple columns of Non.D.Total

```
     Cancer  Total Total.D   Non D Deaths   D Deaths   Non.D.Total.   Non.D.Total.  
1  Cancer 1  11111       111           1111         11          11111          11111
2  Cancer 2  111111      1111          11111        111         111111         111111
3  Cancer 3 111111      1111          11111        111         111111         111111
4  Cancer 4  11111       111           1111         11          11111          11111
5  Cancer 5  11111       111           1111         11          11111          11111
6  Cancer 6  11111       111           1111         11          11111          11111
7  Cancer 7 111111      1111          11111        111         111111         111111
  Non.D.Total. Non.D.Total. Non.D.Total. Non.D.Total. Non.D.Total.
1          11111          11111          11111          11111          11111
2         111111         111111         111111         111111         111111
3         111111         111111         111111         111111         111111
4          11111          11111          11111          11111          11111
5          11111          11111          11111          11111          11111
6          11111          11111          11111          11111          11111
7         115418         115418         115418         115418         115418
```

I do not want the extra six columns.  I believe that it is because of the gather command followed by the mutate, but I am not positive.

Comment: Can you provide `dput(Total.Cancer)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mutate on the column name and not that data frame you are adding. Below is a toy example where I try to add SN across data frames.

```
DF1 <- data.frame("SN" = 1203:1208)
DF2 <- data.frame("SN" = 1203:1208)

DF1 %>% bind_cols(DF2) %>% mutate(sum = DF1 + DF2)
     SN  SN1 sum. sum. sum. sum. sum. sum.
 1 1203 1203 2406 2406 2406 2406 2406 2406
 2 1204 1204 2408 2408 2408 2408 2408 2408

DF1 %>% bind_cols(DF2) %>% mutate(sum = SN + SN1)
    SN  SN1  sum
 1 1203 1203 2406
```

I'm not clear what your desired outcome is but something like this might be what you need(?):

```
Output<-Total.Cancer%>%
gather(Cancer,Total)%>%
bind_cols(D.Total)%>%
bind_cols(Death.Total)%>%
mutate(Non.D.Total=Total-Total.D)
```

Note that we are not calling the data frame but the column in the data frame we want to mutate.